# people who (will) attend the party will

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, future-time

the following sentence shall I add "will"?

> People who (will) attend party tonight will take part in the party tonight.

Besides:

> The girl who will be my girlfriend will take part in my party.
>
> The man who was killed at 6 P.M. will be found at 10 pm.(now is 3 pm)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is usually used without *will*. Using it with *will* brings *will* closer to its sense of *willingness* rather than as an indicator of future time, and so it sounds like

> The people who are willing (or show a desire) to attend the party tonight and demonstrate this desire by actually going to it will take part in the party tonight.

The second sentence is the same. It sounds like you do not have a girlfriend when you say the sentence, so you could mean

> The girl who is willing to be my girlfriend will take part in my party.

or you could be predicting that some girl will become your girlfriend by tonight.

If you have a girlfriend, just use *The girl who is my girlfriend will take part in my party*.

In your third sentence *will* in *will be found at 10pm* comes across as a strong promise. You would probably not use *is found at 10pm* unless describing the situation *after* the girl was found; in this case the use of the present would be the historical present.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help! But I don't know why a grammar book says normally if the main sentence uses simple future tenses, the attributive  clause should use simple present tense to express the future.  like    :"I'll give you everything I find" Is it ambiguous? (1) I will give you everything that I have now. Or something I will get. If I wanna say the lady will be my girl friend, how can I express ? Can I say "The lady who is my girlfriend will be my partner tomorrow?

Comment: In *I'll give you everything I find*, the *find* refers to future time. *The lady who is  my girlfriend will be my partner tomorrow* is fine. It means *the lady who is currently/now my girlfriend*.  I don't exactly know what you mean by *will be my  partner (tomorrow)*.

Comment: But how can we tell…the present situation is used in simple present situation，the future situation is used in simple present situation…The meaning is different Thanks so much！